# Why does ReSharper tell me this expression is always true?

Tags: c#, resharper, boolean-logic, roslyn

I have the following code which will tell me whether or not a certain property is used elsewhere in the code. The idea behind this is to verify whether a property with a `private` setter can be made readonly.

There are multiple gotchas here but the major ones are that an assignment to the property outside the constructor means it won't fire. Furthermore, a static property may only have an assignment in a static constructor to fire the diagnostic. Likewise, an instance property requires only an instance constructor.

Now, most scenarios I have so far are accounted for yet ReSharper gives me a warning in this piece of code and I just can't seem to figure out its logic. The above specification is translated in this bit of code:

```
var isStaticProperty = propertySymbol.IsStatic;
bool hasInstanceUsage = false;
bool hasStaticUsage = false;

foreach (var identifier in outerClass.DescendantNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>())
{
   var memberSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(identifier);
   if (memberSymbol.Symbol.Equals(propertySymbol))
   {
       var constructor = identifier.Ancestors().OfType<ConstructorDeclarationSyntax>()
                                               .FirstOrDefault();
       var isInConstructor = constructor != null;
       var isAssignmentExpression = identifier.Ancestors()
                                               .OfType<AssignmentExpressionSyntax>()
                                               .FirstOrDefault() != null;

       // Skip anything that isn't a setter
       if (!isAssignmentExpression)
       {
           continue;
       }

       // if it is a setter but outside the constructor, we don't report any diagnostic
       if (!isInConstructor)
       {
           return;
       }

       var isStaticConstructor = context.SemanticModel
                                        .GetDeclaredSymbol(constructor).IsStatic;
       if (isStaticConstructor && isStaticProperty)
       {
           hasStaticUsage = true;
       }

       if (!isStaticConstructor && !isStaticProperty)
       {
           hasInstanceUsage = true;
       }
   }
}

// We can't set it to readonly if it's set in both the instance 
//   and the static constructor
// We need a NAND operation: either it's never set, 
//   it's set in ctor 1 or it's set in ctor 2
if (!(hasStaticUsage & hasInstanceUsage))
{
   context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(
                 Rule, property.Identifier.GetLocation(), propertySymbol.Name));
}
```

With the warning being

> Expression is always true

on the line

```
if (!(hasStaticUsage & hasInstanceUsage))
```

Why does it show this warning? There are an unknown amount of descendants so there's an unknown amount of loops. Each loop can set `hasStaticUsage` or `hasInstanceUsage` to `true`, which means that after 2 loops (at the earliest), both values could become `true` and the if condition should fail: a NAND returns `true`, `true`, `true`, `false`.

This is the boolean logic I intend to accomplish:

```
+----------------+------------------+--------+
| hasStaticUsage | hasInstanceUsage | result |
+----------------+------------------+--------+
| false          | false            | true   |
| false          | true             | true   |
| true           | false            | true   |
| true           | true             | false  |
+----------------+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Where is `isStaticProperty` initialized?

Comment: At the same level of `hasInstanceUsage`. I'll include it for completeness' sake, but I don't think it has an impact.

Comment: `I have the following code which will tell me whether or not a certain property is used elsewhere in the code` - isn't this a native feature in VS?

Comment: @Davor: it is, though I still want to implement it myself for the experience. That, and I will want to make this analyzer available in a non-VS setting as well.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - ah, I see. Do go on then :D

Comment: `if (!(hasStaticUsage & hasInstanceUsage))` - I think you meant `&&` instead of `&`.  The end-result is exactly the same, but `&` causes the read to stop and think, *"Wait, why is he using a boolean operator here?"*

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: it's a remnant of my first logic which used XOR (`^`) so while I was messing around with that and moved to a NAND, I didn't think much of it. It's true though, `&&` is just as good and probably more readable even though it didn't affect the problem here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`isStaticProperty` is initialized outside the loop:

```
var isStaticProperty = propertySymbol.IsStatic;
```

If `isStaticProperty` is false, then this expression:

```
 (isStaticConstructor && isStaticProperty)
```

is always false, hence `hasStaticUsage` is false.

If `isStaticProperty` is true, then this expression:

```
 (!isStaticConstructor && !isStaticProperty)
```

is always false, hence `hasInstanceUsage` is false.

In any case `hasStaticUsage` and `hasInstanceUsage` can't both be true at the same time.

Answer (score 14):

You can find out the answer by creating truth table for this expressions.
`isStaticConstructor && isStaticProperty` and `!isStaticConstructor && !isStaticProperty`. Lets do it together.

**isStaticConstructor && isStaticProperty**

```
+---------------------+------------------+--------+
| isStaticConstructor | isStaticProperty | result |
+---------------------+------------------+--------+
| false               | false            | false  |
| false               | true             | false  |
| true                | false            | false  |
| true                | true             | true   |
+---------------------+------------------+--------+
```

**!isStaticConstructor && !isStaticProperty**

```
+---------------------+------------------+--------+
| isStaticConstructor | isStaticProperty | result |
+---------------------+------------------+--------+
| false               | false            | true   |
| false               | true             | false  |
| true                | false            | false  |
| true                | true             | false  |
+---------------------+------------------+--------+
```

So you can see, that there is no any possibility that the both `isStaticConstructor && isStaticProperty` and `!isStaticConstructor && !isStaticProperty` to be `true`.

So, depending on the truth table you had provided, the only possibility that `!(hasStaticUsage & hasInstanceUsage)` becomes `false` is when both expressions are `true` in same time, which is impossible.

Comment: This was indeed the cause -- I just didn't make the connection with `isStaticProperty` and forgot that it couldn't change during cycles.

Answer (score 11):

This block makes it impossible that you will ever set both of those variables to `true`:

```
if (isStaticConstructor && isStaticProperty)
{
     hasStaticUsage = true;
}

if (!isStaticConstructor && !isStaticProperty)
{
    hasInstanceUsage = true;
}
```

Only one of the variables can ever be set to `true`. So your `if` statement will always be the equivalent of `!false == true`.

Comment: The warning persists.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel please see my edit. You have a logic problem elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Turns out it was indeed because of that `isStaticProperty` boolean which I entirely overlooked. I appreciate you searching with me.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel That said, you should still be using `&&` by default, rather than `&`. Even though Ed's explanation is wrong (it's not bitwise - it simply doesn't short circuit, unlike `&&`). `&` should be the special case - where you explicitly *want* all operands to be evaluated, no matter what.